# SAS Output Data between dates

Tags: loops, date, sas

I have a table of customers with effective and termination dates. Instead of having one record, I am trying to create a table that has one record per year & month for each month the member is active. Is there a simple way to create the desired table in SAS? FYI, the raw table will have a few thousand records, and will about a dozen columns, but wanted to keep the example simple for now. Also, there's no line in between the records in the desired table, just added for ease of reference. Thanks.

[Raw and Desire Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f66zI.png)

[image]

Raw Table
Name    Eff_date    Term_Date
John    1/1/2020    3/31/2020
Amy 3/1/2019    3/10/2019

Desired Table
Name    Eff_date    Term_Date   Eff_YM

John    1/1/2020    3/31/2020   202001

John    1/1/2020    3/31/2020   202002

John    1/1/2020    3/31/2020   202003

Amy    3/1/2019     3/10/2019   201903

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  We're not a code writing service, but a code *help* services, so make sure your question includes a *code problem* and the attempt you've made to solve that problem, and specific questions about what you think is wrong or what you don't understand about the problem.  See our [faq] and the [help] for more information. 
 Thanks, and welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- INTCK() will find the number of months between two dates
- INTNX() will increment dates by a specified amount, ie 1 month, 1 week
- An explicit OUTPUT statement will write a new line for each month

  ```
   data have;
   informat name $8. date_start date_end mmddyy10.;
   format name $8. date_start date_end mmddyy10.;
   input Name date_start date_end;
   cards;
   John 1/1/2020 3/31/2020
   Amy 3/1/2019 3/10/2019
   ;;;;
  run;

   data want;
   set have;
   nMonths=intck('month', date_start, date_end, 'C');

   do i=0 to nMonths;
       Effective_YM=intnx('month', date_start, i, 's');
       format effective_YM yymmn6.;
       OUTPUT;
   end;
   drop nMonths;
   run;
  ```